# What do these symbols mean in equations 4 and 5 on this page?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

I'm looking at an old math textbook on the Internet Archive.  On
[page 17 of this pdf](https://ia800501.us.archive.org/5/items/financialmathema032436mbp/financialmathema032436mbp.pdf) at the bottom it has 2 formulas.

> [image]

One has what looks like an apostrophe and the other has a dot (like a decimal but floating).

**Question:**  Can someone explain what these symbols mean?

Comment: Perhaps degrees?

Comment: They just look like a comma and full stop to me.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the first mark is actually a comma (just separating parts of a multiple definition) and the second mark is a period (ending the definition).

Comment: @Matt B : That's what I see as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a comma and a period — mathematical text is still text.

Presumably you wouldn't be as surprised if you saw

> ... it follows that: $I_0=\dfrac{Pdi}{360}$, and $I_e=\dfrac{Pdi}{365}$.

but in order to emphasize and label the equations, we put them on their own line. We nevertheless should keep the punctuation. Take a look at [this MathOverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/q/6675/1916).

Comment: I hadn't seen the MO thread, but that's a great link!